# using pg_dump on remote desktop

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am a novice postgres user employing pgAdminIII on a Windows desktop to connect to a remote postgres db. It connects ok, and everything from within the gui works fine on a very small database. Now I need to make a dump of the whole database (for example called 'mydb') onto my local desktop. I open the command line tool plugin psql.exe and see the prompt

```
mydb=>
```

I  write this:

```
mydb=> pg_dump mydb > /users/username/desktop
```

on pressing Enter, the screen returns

```
mydb->
```

( `=>` has become `->`) and there it stays for as long as I leave it. No file is written.

I cannot find in documentation the significance of `=>` and `->` and would be grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

pg_dump is an executable that is run from the o/s command line, not from within psql.

Answer (score 0):

First: `pg_dump` is **not** a SQL statement. It's a program that you run like `psql.exe`

So to run that locally you need:

```
pg_dump mydb > c:\users\username\desktop
```

`pg_dump` accepts the same connection parameters as `psql`

---

The different types of prompts are explained in the manual - although that is somewhat hidden:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING

You can enter `\set` to see the current definition of those three different prompts.